# Yodlee UserAdministrationService.suspend call

Tags: yodlee

Yodlee has been requesting that we implement suspend calls in our system when users go inactive so they can accurately charge us. I was told that calling UserAdministrationService.suspend() would solve our problems but doing so throws this error: com.yodlee.core.InsufficientPrivilegeException: Accessibility denied.

Which makes me think the suspend call is a call privileged for administration on Yodlee's end. Can someone please verify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behaviour for this API. As this is restricted, hence you won't be able to suspend any user using this API. Please get in touch with Yodlee's support team to help you out with this issue.